# Using Ruby Pony to send emails on RHEL 5.3 I get error NameError - uninitialized constant Net::SMTP::OpenSSL:

Tags: ruby, openssl, sinatra, rhel5, pony

I have a Ruby sinatra application am using Pony to send emails. It works fine from my windows box. But after deploying to RHEL 5.3 server I get following errors.

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Net::SMTP::OpenSSL:
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:197:in `default_ssl_context'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:351:in `enable_starttls_auto'
```

I am using ruby 1.9.2.

Please help to get fix this error. Please let me know if any additional details that I should add

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
yum install libssl-devel libopenssl-ruby openssl libssl
```

Comment: probably just installing `libopenssl-ruby` is fine (if it needs any of the other libs it will pull them in too)